# Hiding AddThis buttons with jQuery until rendered in responsive design

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, addthis, fouc

I've been working on a responsive redesign and I'm trying to reduce the layout shift and flash of unstyled content that occurs when my `AddThis` follow buttons are rendered on the page after being inserted by a `Modernizr` query. Depending on the media query, the `AddThis` code is either inserted into a div with the ID `ss1` or `ss2`. (See [previous solved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256674/cant-seem-to-get-jquery-resize-event-to-work-on-modernizr-media-query-function).)

`AddThis` support suggested I hide the div until the buttons are rendered. I'm a jQuery noob, but I dug around and think I have a partially working solution using `.hide` and `.show`.

Here's a relevant snippet from my main.js:

```
$('#ss1').hide();
$('#ss2').hide();
function initAddThis() {
    addthis.init();
}
function checkMq() {
    if (Modernizr.mq('only screen and (min-width: 1140px)')) {
    $('div#ss1').html('<div class="addthis_toolbox">[snip]</div>');
    $('div#ss1').append('<div style="clear:left">[google search box]</div>');
    $('div#ss2').html(' ');
    addthis.toolbox("#ss1");
    $('#ss1').show();
} else {
    $('div#ss2').html('<div class="addthis_toolbox">[snip]</div>');
    $('div#ss2').append('<div style="clear:left">[google search box]</div>');
    $('div#ss1').html(' ');
    addthis.toolbox("#ss2");
    $('#ss2').show();
    }
}
$(function () {
    initAddThis();
    checkMq();
    $(window).resize(function () {
        checkMq();
    });
});
```

Despite the fact that I first hide the `ss1` and `ss2` divs, I still get that
initial FOUC. When I resize the window back and forth it works as planned.
It's just the initial load that has the issue. I'm assuming that perhaps the time between the render call `initAddThis();` and the jQuery `.show` in `checkMq();` is too short?

Comment: I cant help but feel adding a `$(window).resize` listener is a bit overkill for most use cases. It feels like your adding a lot of complexity to fix an edge case. How many 'regular' folk will be resizing your page to marvel at the responsiveness?

Comment: You hit it with laser precision. After looking at several use cases I realized the resize stuff wasn't needed and just chose one spot for the AddThis buttons. HOWEVER, the crux of the question still remains. Even stripping it down to a bare AddThis call and a .show still gets me an FOUC and a layout shift.